# Info about this coin obstacle course game from Micki Gemla Sweden?

Tags: identify-this-game

I found this old coin obstacle course game from Micki Gemla Made in Sweden?

There where no hard cover so can anyone help me with the name of this game?
And also maybe give some more information about it?

[image: Micki Gemla Made in Sweden Coin Game]
[image: Micki Gemla Made in Sweden Coin Game Close Up]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a miniature golf sim game played with coins instead of balls. It was made in 1970 by Micki Leksaker Sweden. It was just called "[Minigolf](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24887/minigolf)"

[image: game box and components]

(Image from https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-1970-wooden-roll-coin-484615066 )

You play by rolling your coin down the tall slot/slide to take each shot.

Rules (printed on the box):

> **Playing rules for “roll-a-coin” mini golf game**
> Any number of people can play. The game comprises of [sic] nine different obstacles numbered from 1 to 9.
> Obstacles number 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 each have two parts.
> One plays with an ordinary quarter coin or the Swedish 5 öre coin that is included, which is placed in the slot of the stand positioned at the edge of the playing surface.
> The player is awarded one point for each play plus the number of points shown in the divisions (if the coin does not roll into the cup). The player may have 7 plays for each obstacle. If he does not pass the obstacle, then he will receive a 12 point penalty.

> The player who received the smallest number of points is the winner